# Start processing async tasks while adding them to the event loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio

A common pattern with asyncio, like the one shown [here](https://medium.com/@santhoshhari/efficient-web-scraping-with-pythons-asynchronous-programming-6b9e730f1ff7), is to add a collection of coroutines to a list, and then `asyncio.gather` them.

For instance:

```
async def some_task(i):
    # Do something asynchronously with i

tasks = [some_task(i) for i in range(100)]

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(**tasks))
```

Here, the execution order of this code is such that none of the tasks are running while we build up the list. We add task 1 to the list, then task 2, etc. and **then** we add the tasks 1-100 to the event loop.

---

However, I want task creation itself to be part of the event loop. I want task 1 to be scheduled immediately as it's created, and then when task is waiting for something on another thread, return to task creation and create task 2 and add it to the event loop.

I believe this would give me better concurrency from my async code. Is this possible?

---

For example, my first thought would be to put task creation into a coroutine and schedule tasks as they are created:

```
async def some_task(i):
    # Do something asynchronously with i

async def generate_tasks(loop):
    tasks = []
    for i in range(100):
        task = loop.create_task(some_task(i))
        tasks.append(loop)
    await asyncio.gather(**tasks)

loop.run_until_complete(generate_tasks())
```

However, because my `generate_tasks` never uses `await`, execution is never passed back to the event loop, so the entirety of `generate_tasks` will run before `some_task()` is run at all.

---

But then, if I `await` each task as they are created, it will wait for each task to complete before moving on to the next task, giving me no concurrency at all!

```
async def generate_tasks(loop):
    tasks = []
    for i in range(100):
        await some_task(i)

loop.run_until_complete(generate_tasks())
```

Comment: It won't give you better concurrency. When you execute `tasks = [some_task(i) for i in range(100)]`, all 100 tasks have been created. `some_task(i)` returns a task object. And what `asyncio.gather` does is adding all tasks into loop and awaiting all of them. So you won't get better concurrency.

Comment: But that creation of tasks (the list comprehension) is entirely serial. If task creation were part of the event loop I'd get some parallelism (as much as you can using async)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, because my `generate_tasks` never uses `await`, execution is never passed back to the event loop

You can use `await asyncio.sleep(0)` to force yielding to the event loop inside `for`. But that is unlikely to make a difference, creating a task/coroutine pair is really efficient.

Before optimizing this, measure (with something as simple as `time.time` if need be) how much time it takes to execute the `[some_task(i) for i in range(100)]` list comprehension. Then consider whether dispersing that time (possibly making it take **longer** to finish due to increased scheduling overhead) will make any difference for your application. The results might surprise you.

Comment: So I could `task = loop.create_task(some_task(i)); tasks.append(loop); await asyncio.sleep(0)` to create the task, add it to the event loop, and then execute it immediately? That sounds like what I want. I will check performance but this still solves what I asked about

Comment: @Miguel Yes, except there should be no need to do that. asyncio is about scheduling around timeouts and blocking network calls. Creating a task (or 100 of them) should be pretty much instantaneous, and adding spurious context switches could actually slow things down.